# Redirect from facebook browser to Safari Apple

Tags: javascript, redirect, user-agent

this script redirects users from facebook browser to google chrome on android devices, I need it to do the same on :

- Instagram browser on android (google chrome) and iphone(safari)
- Facebook browser on iphone(redirect to safari)

here is the running code now :

```
<script>
    function isFacebookApp() {
        var ua = navigator.userAgent || navigator.vendor || window.opera;
        return (ua.indexOf("FBAV") > -1) || (ua.indexOf("FBAN") > -1);
    }
if (isFacebookApp()) {
    var currentLink = location.href;
    if (currentLink.indexOf('https') > -1) {
        var currentLink = currentLink.replace('https://', '');
        currentLink = currentLink.replace('www.', '');
        var chromeLink = "intent://" + currentLink + "#Intent;scheme=https;package=com.android.chrome;end";
        window.location.href = chromeLink;
    }
    if (currentLink.indexOf('http') > -1) {
        var currentLink = currentLink.replace('http://', '');
        currentLink = currentLink.replace('www.', '');
        var chromeLink = "intent://" + currentLink + "#Intent;scheme=http;package=com.android.chrome;end";
        window.location.href = chromeLink;
    }
} 
</script>
```

thanks

Comment: to detect Instagram its easy just check for `Instagram` in userAgent which you can use on android devices.
I am also searching answer for redirecting to safari