# Redirect Facebook/Instagram URLs to Safari/Chrome rather than internal web browser

Tags: android, google-chrome, redirect, instagram

I've used the below code from this question - [Redirect from facebook browser to Safari Apple](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70259484/21046837) for redirecting FB links to Chrome rather than opening up in the internal FB browser/webview.

I now need this to work for FB links on iphones/tablets - redirect to safari or possibly Chrome if thats what the user is using.

and Instagram links on iphone/tablets redirect to safari or possibly Chrome if thats what the user is using.

```
<script>
    function isFacebookApp() {
        var ua = navigator.userAgent || navigator.vendor || window.opera;
        return (ua.indexOf("FBAV") > -1) || (ua.indexOf("FBAN") > -1);
    }
if (isFacebookApp()) {
    var currentLink = location.href;
    if (currentLink.indexOf('https') > -1) {
        var currentLink = currentLink.replace('https://', '');
        currentLink = currentLink.replace('www.', '');
        var chromeLink = "intent://" + currentLink + "#Intent;scheme=https;package=com.android.chrome;end";
        window.location.href = chromeLink;
    }
    if (currentLink.indexOf('http') > -1) {
        var currentLink = currentLink.replace('http://', '');
        currentLink = currentLink.replace('www.', '');
        var chromeLink = "intent://" + currentLink + "#Intent;scheme=http;package=com.android.chrome;end";
        window.location.href = chromeLink;
    }
} 
</script>
```